# Filter data form CSV file in java

Tags: java, csv, file-handling

I'm building a webapp get information from a CSV file and display it to a table. In this form have some filter component to filter information to display.

If data from database it become so easy when we using query commands but data from CSV file so i don't know way to to filter it.

Can you suggest me some way to do it, thank all.

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache POI library. This library can manipulate almost all spreadsheets and the AutoFilter interface can be used to implement filters.

Useful links:

[Apache POI documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/index.html)

[AutoFilter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/AutoFilter.html) in Apache POI